# How to delete old images from public folder on update using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, image, public

I want to delete older images in public folder on update:

My Controller code:

```
try {
    $path = public_path('profile_images');
    @mkdir($path, '0777', true);

    $image = base64_decode($image);

    $imageName = str_random(10).'.'.'png';
    Storage::disk('profile-image')->put($imageName, $image);


    $path = asset('public/profile_images/' . $imageName);

    $this->userBasicInfo->where('user_id', $user_id)->update(['profile_pic' => $path]);

    return response(['status' => true, 'message' => 'Image Uploaded successfully', 'data' => ['profile_image' => $path]], 200);

} catch (\Exception $ex) {
    return response(['status' => false, 'message' => $ex->getMessage()], 500);
}
```

How can I achieve the delete functionality?

Comment: can you edit into my code?

Comment: did not helped me

Comment: You can store the relative path instead of the asset url. So in your case `$imageName`, this way you can later call `Storage::disk('profile-image')->delete($oldImageName);` when you want to update the profile pic.

Comment: You must ger ur old image first, then unlink it before you put new file and replace to DB,

Comment: Try to avoid saving many files in one folder. If you have few thousands files in one folder (not using subfolders), files reading operations could be slow

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
File::delete($file_path)
```

Comment: Call to undefined method phpDocumentor\Reflection\File::delete()

Comment: @syed1234 Let's ` use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File` on the top file